# failing to move file from input folder to error folder

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to run a code where i am read files sheets. Issue i am facing is, if there is a file which has no sheet named `SheetSum` I am not able to move it to error location.

**example**:

```
def read_file(data_file):
    # data_file = '\rr\ex.xlsx'
    sheets = {}
    try:
        print("Reading file: "+data_file)
        sheets['df_1'] = pd.read_excel(open(data_file,'rb'), 'SheetSum')
    except Exception as excpt:
        print("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
    return sheets

read_file(file)
shutil.move( file, dirpath +'\\processed_files')
```

Getting an error as:

`[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

Updates:

> If `finally` is present, it specifies a **cleanup handler**. The `try`
>   clause is executed, including any `except` and `else` clauses. If an
>   exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the
>   **exception is temporarily saved**. The `finally` clause is executed. If
>   there is a saved exception it is re-raised at the end of the `finally`
>   clause. If the `finally` clause raises another exception, the saved
>   exception is set as the context of the new exception.

..More [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally)

**Accepted Solution worked like charm.**

Comment: sometimes windows file preview is the obstacle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing the file before attempting to move it.
So something like

```
def read_file(data_file):
    # data_file = '\rr\ex.xlsx'
    sheets = {}
    try:
        print("Reading file: "+data_file)
        sheets_file = open(data_file,'rb')
        sheets['df_1'] = pd.read_excel(sheets_file, 'SheetSum')
    except Exception as excpt:
        print("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
    finally:
        sheets_file.close()
    return sheets

read_file(file)
shutil.move( file, dirpath +'\\processed_files')
```

The problem is the file opens, is handed to the pandas method, and when an exception occurs, your file is never closed.

Adding a `finally` to your try except block ensures that your file is always closed.